# Javafx XYChart setting Y axis decimal value creates more decimals

Tags: javafx, decimal, precision

I've created a XYChart where X axis are names and Y axis are decimal numbers (floats)

The problem is, when I change chart lists from a table with a listener it works wonderful, but when I change it from a "forward" button, it doesnt.

forward button, only selects the next table item so in theory should work, since doing it manually works. But it doesnt.

Debugging the code I've realized that, when inserting values to the chart manually selecting the table row, the decimal inserted inside the XYChart object is: 3.692

but selecting from button results in something on the lines of: 3.6919999999004857554

I've tried:

- Using float directly
- Using double directly
- Using BigDecimal directly
- Setting bigDecimal's scale to 3 values and Half Up rounding mode
- Producing float and double from BigDecimal
- Using String.valueOf and then going back with Float.valueOf
- Hardcoding a float value like 2.2f (Resulting in 2.200000000000000324234)

All of them produces a "correct" decimal stored in a variable (decimalNumber in the code), but when inserted into the chart, they show the wrong value, which ultimately is causing my UI to crash.

This is the line inserting decimals

`dataSerie.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(hour, decimalNumber));`

**Here you can see how adding new Series goes as expected**
[image: Correct value]

**Here you can clearly see how adding new serires DOESNT go as expected**
[image: Incorrect value]

As you can see, 2.2f is inserted as 2.200000047683716

method adding the value to the chart

```
private void addDataToSerie(XYChart.Series dataSerie, String hora, float consumo) {
    dataSerie.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(hora, 2.2f));
    }
```

Comment: What is a "forward" button? What is, precisely, the issue? Are you saying that if you do `XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(hour, 2.2)` and then later do `data.getYValue()` it's producing something other than `2.2`? (What do you actually mean by "show the wrong value"?)

Comment: @James_D sorry for my english, im spanish. Forward button just changes the list filling the chart, so the chart shows something different. The issue is that I set "2.2f", debug the chart value I previously set and shows other than that (2.20000000000324234)

Comment: Post a [mre]; it's just not clear what you mean.

Comment: @James_D tried posting the method. But the method is only failing under really specific conditions that I dont really understand, that's why I ask for help. It's working when I call it from a side, but it's not working when call it from a different one. The only difference I can appreciate when calling it from different places is just that decimal stuff (image added to main post)

Comment: aand yes, ```System.out.println(dataSerie.getData().get(0));``` shows other than 2.2. exactly shows the number you can see in thes second image in the main post